# Help identify BMX please - possibly 80s or early 90s

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

I recently picked up this old BMX bike for AU$5 at a garage sale. I was originally only interested in the Skyway Turbo Disc chain wheel, but decided I would strip the whole thing and give it a new lease on life. If anyone can ID the make, and even better the model, I would be very grateful. The frame has a distinctive gusset at the intersection of the top tube, down tube and head tube.

[image: Bike as purchased]

[image: stripped frame - gusset]

Comment: I can't help with your question,  but the bike frame definitely looks robust.  Good work for rebuilding it.

Comment: Unfortunately, gussets like that are common on BMX bikes, so you'll have to make close comparisons of its exact shape as well as other features of the frame such as the shape of the seat stays and dropouts. I'm leaning towards a Mongoose, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I'd also recommend posting your photos to the forums at BMXmuseum.com. Experts there might know it right away.

Answer (score 5):

PMX Clubmaster from [bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/pmx/104712)

bmxmuseum has PMX bikes from 1982 to 1984 named "Clubmaster" or just "Club"

The bike pictured does not have original parts.

[image]

According to [this link](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=352437) the PMX Club is a steel frame bike from Germany

Answer (score 1):

I know it's years later but that could be a Webco however as stated a lot of BMX bikes had that same style and look back in the day, not sure if you solidified it's identity so I thought I'd chime in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Instead of asking everyone here to go and do their own research to see if this is a good answer, you could greatly improve it by finding a decent picture of the bike you're talking about and posting it here for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Raleigh Rampar r10**

I had one in the early `80s.

[image]
<sub>From https://ashopsz.top/products.aspx?cname=raleigh+rampar+bmx&cid=149</sub>

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! BMX bicycles (and all bicycles in general) do look very much the same very often, so it would improve your answer a lot if you could provide any information to back it up, e.g. pictures, links to manufacturer catalogs for the product, pointing out unique frame features making it distinctive from everything else on the market etc.

Comment: That's a good start because it gives some words to search for.   Do you have any citations or supporting info?   A clear photo of a rampar r10  would make this answer more comparable.   Every photo I can see shows either two different sized holes in the gusset, or a caret-shaped cutout.  There is a good resemblance though.

Comment: I'm also editing the word "Raleigh" into your answer because it seems plausible.

Comment: I don't see any images online of Raleigh Rampar r10 models that match the OP's frame. Can you provide one?

Comment: Added a stock photo of this bike.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking at a early form of a [DK bike](https://dkbicycles.com/). I had one just like it. If the serial numbers are on the bottom you can Google it and it'll let you know

Comment: This is a bit short on details; you could greatly improve your answer by finding a decent picture of a bike like you're talking about and posting it here for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a 1972 Kuwahara I know because I have one.

[image]
 <sub>from https://www.flitebmx.com/pages/kuwahara</sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles. This answer is short of details and will be flagged.  You could greatly improve it by finding a decent picture (or better yet, pictures) of the bike you're talking about and posting it here for comparison.

Comment: Steve - I've found a stock photo of this bike, does it match?  If you have yours still, please take a photo and add it to this answer with [edit]

Comment: Yes bud that’s the exact bike. Mine still not reassembled no where near complete. But that’s the one bud

Comment: It’s nothing like a raeleigh at all. Different in 3 places. People shouldn’t post a guess!

Comment: That's why you should post more explanation. Explain those differences and point out why your answer is the correct one. To my untrained eye, the rear dropout area if this Kuwahara is also different. The PMX is the right one.